# Is there any other program/software to work as if coding in VBA

Tags: vba

I might not make much sense but is there any software out there which is capable of coding/running like VBA in excel, mainly for calculations:

Thanks

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript

Answer (score 0):

you can try the C API for Excel

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687829.aspx
```